# Node.js GC mark-compact

Tags: javascript, node.js, garbage-collection

I'm having an issue with an application that uses a in-memory dictionaries (instantiated via new Constructor(bla, fla, pla)).
As soon as resident memory size approaches ~100-150 Mbs the mark-compact phase takes more than a second. Each hundred megs adds one more second.

The behavior can be reproduced by running the following:

```
node --trace_gc test-memory.js
```

test_memory.js:

```
var http      = require('http'),
    Construct = function () {
        this.theField = Math.random();
    },
    storage   = [];

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var i = 100000;

    while (--i) {
        storage.push(new Construct());
    }

    res.end('Lots of data generated.');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

Then do curl localhost:1337 for some time and watch this:

```
Scavenge 143.5 -> 143.5 MB, 2 ms.
Mark-sweep 143.5 -> 143.5 MB, 943 ms.
Mark-compact 143.5 -> 143.5 MB, 1306 ms.
Scavenge 143.5 -> 143.5 MB, 2 ms.
Mark-sweep 143.5 -> 143.5 MB, 937 ms.
Mark-compact 143.5 -> 143.5 MB, 1189 ms.
Scavenge 143.5 -> 143.5 MB, 2 ms.
Mark-sweep 143.5 -> 143.5 MB, 935 ms.
Mark-compact 143.5 -> 143.5 MB, 1191 ms.
Scavenge 143.5 -> 143.5 MB, 1 ms.
Mark-sweep 143.5 -> 143.5 MB, 1015 ms.
Mark-compact 143.5 -> 143.5 MB, 1218 ms.
Scavenge 143.5 -> 143.5 MB, 2 ms.
Mark-sweep 143.5 -> 143.5 MB, 937 ms.
Mark-compact 143.5 -> 143.5 MB, 1195 ms.
```

As far as I can tell the GC tries to move around objects that are not going to be freed anyway.

The only solution I found is to move these objects into a Buffer, but for my application that would mean an overhead of JSON.stringify|JSON.parse which most likely will end up in more CPU time. Plus that will require quite a rewrite.

I understand that it may be more of a v8 problem, but may be there is some way to circumvent the GC for objects that are not going to be released?

node.js version is 0.6.11

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to compare performance with using REDIS or Membase? As far I can see, you reach the level where this can be considered an in-memory database, so you can try to compare to actually using one these.

Comment: I didn't, but it will not be viable in my case.
The point is, if I cache immutable data I can write my application like this (i.e. synchronously):

`user.item = storage.get('Item', itemId)`

Using any kind of external storage will make me use the async approach.

Also, I have found a leak in my app so the problem is somewhat mitigated.